# MVC Jquery response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in jquery

```
     success: function(response)
      {     alert( response.id);  

      }
```

My question is, how do I pass a response value from an ActionResult Controller in .NET c# so that jQuery can get it? Say I wanted to pass the id value from the Controller so that jquery can get a hold of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to call an Action from jQuery and get back some results... In that case you can use JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult Action(int id)
{
    ...
    return Json(new { id = id });
}
```

and then `response.id` should "work".

Comment: Thank you for your response. So it would definitely need to be a JsonResult vs just a regulre ActionResult for this to work, correct?

Comment: Yes, for this kind of scenarios you should work with JsonResult/Json.

Answer (score 0):

this articles discuss different response type from ActionResult Controller in .NET c#  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do something like this

```
success: function(response)
      {    
          //this should turn the returned data into a json object
          var obj = $.parseJson(response);
          alert(obj.id);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
public ActionResult action(int id){

   string data= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // you can convert your object to json and then send to ajax call back

   return ok(data);
}
```